# Common SDK (smarttv-alliance): no video playback

Tags: television, lg, smart-tv-alliance

Trying the SDK from the smart tv alliance, I worry about it not playing videos in the vbox.
The menu and browser works well, but e.g. when trying the video sample project within SDK, it does not play videos there. => screen remains black in the content area...

It's a smart tv virtualization, so I hope it supports video playback and is not a missing feature (as in some android simulators).

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly like a normal site or HTML document...
Add your video like you would do normally.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK emulator does not supprot much formats to be played except of the mp4 progressive download. What exactly are you trying to stream?

STeN